# How create a __len__ function on __init__?

Tags: python, object, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I remove the `__size` attribute in this object ?

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.__size = size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__size
```

How can the init function create the len function ? Lambda function ?

PS: In my real case, I have some calculations to do in this len function, but after instantiation the result is always the same (like a tuple for instance). It might be great to save this result in a function without any hidden attribute.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  pseudo-private attributes tend to be the best way to memoize data in an object, but your question is a bit vague to give any better suggestions for.

Comment: as it is now, nothing is wrong, I would call the member `_size` though. [Explicit is better than implicit.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: In short: You should not struggle for removing that attribute. It is better this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend this, but you can use a simple lambda function

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.__len__ = lambda: size


>>> len(Object(3))
3
```

The reasons why I would not recommend this are subsummed in the Zen of Python: Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex.

If you are using an instance variable, then it is explicit, you have better stacktraces for errors, you can use doctests in you `__len__` function and the code is easier to understand when reading and updating it.

Comment: Why would you not recommend this?

Comment: It introduces overhead without adding functionality in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @recursive Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex. If you are using an instance variable, then it is explicit, you have better stacktraces for errors, you can use doctests in you __len__ function and the code is easier to understand when reading and updating it.

Comment: This does not work for Python 3.x. Gives error `TypeError: object of type 'Object' has no len()` see http://ideone.com/ugAT8k

Comment: Nor does it for 2.x in new-style classes.

Comment: Does it have to be `lambda self: size` instead?  Think most code expects `len` to be an instance method.

Comment: @sr2222 The builtin function `len()` does a class lookup on the instance method `__len__()`; the instance dictionary isn't looked up on this, however.

Comment: This is a good answer due to "I would not recommend this" - but it shows incorrect code. In Python 2.x one should always use new-style classes

Comment: Add the method to the class: `Object.__len__ = lambda self: size`

Answer (score 2):

As it is not possible to let `__len__` be a instance attribute in order to be used via `len()`, you must define it in the class. But as there is no restriction otherwise, you could define an instance attribute `__len__` so that your namespace isn't polluted.

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.__len__ = lambda: size
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len__()
```

This looks confusing (and because of this is probably froned upon), but it works.

It works because the class attribute `__len__()`, being the `def`-ed function, calls the instance attribute `__len__()`, which is the lambda from `__init__()`.

Having shown what is possible, I wouldn't recommend it, because it can be very confusing.

Your original solution is much better.